# Add DropDownList to a gridview cell

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to do a DropDownList in one cell of the gridview but I only can add columns.

```
<Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>  
             <asp:DropDownList  ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataValueField="Catalog" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"></asp:DropDownList>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

How can I add an only dropdownlist to a gridview?

Comment: Are you mean that you have more data inside a table but you want to add one DropDownList to a specific cell ??

Comment: Why do you need it in a datagridview?

Comment: Is for special app, I'm migrating a desktop app for the web, I have one column that has one cell that contains a comboboxcell for see other values of the gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in asp.net forum, here let you the link if somebody need it:
[Add DropDownList to a gridview cell](http://forums.asp.net/p/1878760/5288343.aspx/1?Re%20Add%20DropDownList%20to%20a%20gridview%20cell)

Answer (score 1):

To add DropDownList to GridView cell you should use ItemTemplates. You can find more details [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178294%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Also another sample is [here](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/169_DropDownList_Inside_GridView__Method_1_.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, but this suggestion not function for do a dropDownList in a GridView cell.

Comment: See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx you'll find a lot of example which hash DropDownList in GridView cell and explains how to access and update data in the DropDownList

Comment: also http://www.ezineasp.net/post/Edit-Update-GridView-DropDownList-SelectedValue.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but this make the entire column as DropDownList. I need make a only one cell of the GridView DropDownList.